# iOS - Superview gesture recognizer getting called when not wanted, can't cancel child view touch event

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a super view that has a UITapGestureRecognizer on it.  It allows touches within the view because there are clickable items within the view.

When these items are clicked on, I want to take a specific action, not the generic one that covers the entire superview.  Unfortunately in my TouchDown event of my child control I don't know how to stop the event here.  I know I could create a kludge flag, but this seems like the wrong way to go.

Any advice?

James

Comment: Are you able to show a simplified snippet of how your views are setup? Are your "child controls" buttons with actions and targets set and then the container is a UIView with a tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: @marcus.ramsden - Yes, its a UIView container with a UITapGestureRecognizer and a button that is a child.

Comment: Been testing this further.  Created a sandbox with just the view container and child control and this scenario works fine.  So it must be something else.  Perhaps the fact it is in a UITableView... not sure.  I'll post back here if I discover anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got a solution.  Totally my problem.  I was playing around with trying to get all touches to work and at one point I had set cancelTouchesInView = true on the UITapGestureRecognizer superview.  While this didn't stop the other touches from happening, for whatever reason the touches carried through to the superview as well.  I understand that this explanation probably makes no sense, but that's what did it.  Still trying to wrap my head around how iOS does touch.